# Valid Distribution Function?

Tags: calculus, probability

Given a Probability Density Function ${f_X}(x)$, how can I prove that ${f_X}(x)$ is a valid distribution function? I already known that ${f_X}(x) \ge 0$ and $\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{f_X}(x)dx = 1} $ for all $x$.

Thanks!

Comment: If it is a Borel function, then you're safe.